# AttributeError: 'bind_all' is not allowed, when using pandastable with tabview

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter, pandastable

I'm trying to display a CSV table in a  frame inside a TAB in tabview, using customtkinter and pandastable as modules.
I don't know why but it's giving me this error:
`AttributeError: 'bind_all' is not allowed, when using pandastable with tabview`

It's not giving any errors when I try to do exact same thing inside the main window, or using an external window.

```
import customtkinter
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
import pandas as pd
import traceback

class MyTabView(customtkinter.CTkTabview):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.toplevel_window = None 
        
        self.TAB1 = "Initial configuration"
        self.TAB2 = "Progress status"
        self.TAB3 = "Final result"
        
        # create tabs
        self.add(self.TAB1)
        self.add(self.TAB2)
        self.add(self.TAB3)
        self.tab(self.TAB1).grid_columnconfigure((0,1),weight=1)
        
        # add widgets on tabs
        
        self.button_file_path = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.tab(self.TAB1), text="Select CSV file", command=self.get_file_path)
        self.button_file_path.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky = "we")
        
        self.select_column_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master = self.tab(self.TAB1), text="Select column from CSV")
        self.select_column_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky = "we")
        self.select_column_option = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(master = self.tab(self.TAB1), values=[])
        self.select_column_option.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20, pady=10, sticky = "we")
        
    
    def showCSV(self):
        
        self.csv_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.tab(self.TAB1))
        self.csv_frame.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , padx = 20, pady = 20, sticky = "nswe", columnspan = 2)
        egypt_df = pd.read_csv(self.file_path, encoding='utf-8')
        try:
            self.table = pt = Table(parent=self.csv_frame, dataframe=egypt_df, showtoolbar=False, showstatusbar=False, editable=False)
            pt.show()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Could not display CSV table:", e)
            traceback.print_exc()
        # if self.toplevel_window is None or not self.toplevel_window.winfo_exists():
        #     self.toplevel_window = CsvTableWindow(self.file_path)  # create window if its None or destroyed
        # else:
        #     self.toplevel_window.focus()  
    
    def get_file_path(self):
        print("button1")
        self.file_path =  fd.askopenfilename()   
        try:
            assert ((".csv") in self.file_path)
            print(self.file_path)            
            egypt_df = pd.read_csv(self.file_path, encoding='utf-8')
            print(egypt_df)
        except AssertionError:
            # Da cambiare con popup
            print("This is not a CSV file!")    
        self.button_show_csv =customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.tab(self.TAB1), text = "Show CSV table", command=self.showCSV)
        self.button_show_csv.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=10, sticky = "we")


class CsvTableWindow(customtkinter.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, path):
        print(path)
        super().__init__()
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 20, pady =20, sticky = "nswe")
        egypt_df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='utf-8')
        try:
            self.table = pt = Table(parent=self, dataframe=egypt_df, showtoolbar=False, showstatusbar=False, editable=False)
            pt.show()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Could not display CSV table:", e)
            traceback.print_exc()

class App(customtkinter.CTk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        self.geometry("800x600")
        self.title("Similarity search engine")
        self.tab_view = MyTabView(master=self)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.tab_view.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky = "nswe")


app = App()

app.mainloop()
```

I tried different combinations of frames and windows, and it didn't change much

Comment: This sounds like a poorly defined feature of customtkinter.

Comment: @BryanOakley yeah I was thinking the same thing. 
Thank for your response.